# Accessing OpenGL ES extensions with the Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

If I run `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` in my NDK code (C/C++), I get a list of 38 supported extensions. But if I access OpenGL ES 3.2 in Java and run `GLES32.glGetString(GLES32.GL_EXTENSIONS)`, I get a list of 74 supported extensions.

I assume the problem is that my NDK application links the libGLESv3.so library, which doesn't provide any features beyond OpenGL ES 3.0. It would be nice if there was a libGLESv32.so library, but I can't find one.

Is there any way to access those extra extensions in an NDK application?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a GLESv32.so library (in principle there shouldn't even be a GLESv3.so); OpenGLES 3.x is designed to be backwards compatible with OpenGL ES 2.x, so all applications should link with GLESv2.so even for GLESv3 functionality.

Comment: I tried linking to libGLESv2.so, but I got a number of undefined references (glMapBufferRange, glBindVertexArray, etc.). The libGLESv3.so file is twice as large as the libGLESv2.so file, so it seems unlikely that libGLESv2.so provides all the functionality of libGLESv3.so.

Comment: OK - sounds like Android has done something "special" here.

Comment: libGLESv3.so is the correct one. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#opengles-3_2 and backward compatible means later one contains former one.

Comment: Maybe related issue: remove symbol versions from libGLESv3.so for pre-N https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/265 >The M CDD actually required that libGLESv3.so was a symlink to libGLESv2.so, which actually means that M devices are required to have a broken libGLESv3.so

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` doesn't return the full list of extensions.

To get the full list, you need to call `glGetIntegerv` with `GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS`. Then you can iterate through the extensions by calling `glGetStringi` with `GL_EXTENSIONS`.

Comment: Actually, this wasn't the issue at all. The issue was that `__android_log_print` truncates the content to 1 KB per line. `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` does return the full list of extensions.